# How does unity map a lightmap onto the scene?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I built a scene in Unity 5.6 , set the Directional light Mode to be "Baked", baked the scene and got 6 files,they are:

> LightingData.asset , Lightmap-0_comp_dir.png , Lightmap-0_comp_light.exr , Lightmap-1_comp_dir.png , Lightmap-1_comp_light.exr , ReflectionProbe-0.exr

They look like this:
[image]
[image]

I want to know what the 6 files are, and how does unity map the lightmaps onto the scene? Also, I'm curious about that how does Unity bake the scene and get the lightmap?

#### Hope someone can help me , thanks a lot!!

Comment: Based on a project I worked on over 2.5 years ago, the 5th (?) file there is basically a PNG (?) image that's cleverly UV-mapped to the scene from the perspective of the light.  I once had to go in and tweak the results because a particular object wasn't mapping nicely and it was easier to tweak the lightmap than to figure out why.

Comment: Now, I'm trying to generate lightmaps for low resolutions LODs from lightmap of high resolution LOD. I need to know exactly how does lightmaps are baked and what the 6 files are and what their data structure are.

Comment: I don't think you can. I'm 90% sure that lightmaps are of a *fixed size* (that is: the image files themselves are always the same pixel dimensions) and trying to scale them (or their contents) won't work (because of the UVs). You can try scaling down the whole file, but no guarantees.